# How can I use JSON API Resource in a Lumen project?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

In Laravel it can be done as simply as it is described here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources.

Some says, API Resources is not meant for Lumen. However, just for the sake of this question, I want to know, strictly, if there is a way on how to add Laravel JSON API Resource in a Lumen project (the package `use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;` is missing from freshly created Lumen project).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

API Resources are available in lumen, the files are there under: `vendor\illuminate\http\Resources`.
what's missing is the artisan command to generate them. So just create the files manually, something like:
`app\Http\Resources\UserResource.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class UserResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
        ];
    }
}
```

I don't know who says, API Resources is not meant for Lumen, but that's not true.

Comment: For Lumen 5.8, if you add the package flipbox/lumen-generator: ```composer require flipbox/lumen-generator``` you will be able to use it with the artisan command ```artisan make:resource myresource```

Comment: there is anything about resource in lumen docs, so thanks for the reply

Answer (score -4):

Upgrade your laravel to 6.xx
run

> composer install

then only you see the Resource classes under

> vendor/illuminate/http/  directory

Answer (score -5):

if you want to send response in json then use in your controller 
return response($res, 200);
here 200 is stauts code

Comment: Resources is for not using View layer in the controllers.